# What are the advantages of using bower over minified javascript files?

Tags: javascript, bower

I know what *bower* does.

But wanted to see if there is any real advantage of using bower files in a `AngularJS` app instead of just having the **minified javascript** file?

Comment: I didn't know these two things were mutually exclusive…!?

Comment: @deceze Did not get what you wanted to say.

Comment: Why can you not use bower to install dependencies and then use the `.min.` files which are *often* included in the distribution?

Comment: @deceze I am using Ionic. So bower downloads lot of other files, which I am not sure if needed. Wanted to have as minimum of code as possible.

Comment: That's an overrated concern. If anything, write a build script which produces a final build with only the resources you need. Forgoing the convenience of bower during development because you want to trim down the final product is the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: @deceze Oh. Ok. Got you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those libs are not really your project's source code. They are dependencies. To keep your source code clean, it's better to declare your dependencies in your package.json file if you use npm or in your bower config file if you use bower.

When others download the project, they do not need to download the deps.

Using bower or npm can also help you upgrade your deps conveniently.

Comment: I don't understand your logic in downloading the dependancies. A user will still have to install them through their respective manager. They just won't come from the repo. So it's git pull && bower/npm install (extra commands if anything)

Comment: it's okay for a small project. when getting bigger, it's hard to manage the deps (because deps have their deps) and the version.

Comment: ps. for now, it's better to only use npm over bower.